# Zero downtime copy/restore of a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, restore

I have a production server with static (no deletes/updates) PostgreSQL database, serving a huge amount of read queries.

Once a week or two I have to update my database with new data. Right now the process it pretty complicated, so I'm using a separate server to build new database from the scratch.

So, at some point I have live production server with outdated data and up to date database on some secondary server.

First I've tried backup/restore approach, but it resulted in 5 minutes downtime, which is not acceptable.

Then I've tried adding `--single-transaction` flag to `pg_restore` call, but it resulted in 2 minuted downtime, because all requests to PostgreSQL hanged for a couple of minutes after transaction was committed.

The best solution I came up with so far is to copy new database to production server under some new name and then switch my application to it.

But I wonder if there's any better solution, which will allow me to ship new data to production server without restarting my application.

Comment: Does 'new data' mean `INSERT`s only?  If not, some sort of logical replication may help you - it won't make the process much simpler, though.

Comment: Does this complex procedure (*"update my database with new data"*) have only inserts?

Comment: No, it's not only inserts. Otherwise, there wouldn't be any problem pushing it to production database.

Comment: The canonical solution is 1.start transaction 2. DML. 3.commit transaction, while the readers keep reading. If you know already why that wouldn't work in your case, please add it to your question.

Comment: @DanielVérité yes, it should work. For some reason I thought that `pg_restore` does it by default. But now I realize that I just missed `--single-transaction` flag.

Comment: @DanielVérité just tried `pg_restore` with `--single-transaction`, but it resulted in two minuted downtime, because all requests to PostgreSQL hanged for two minutes after transaction was committed.

Comment: If you're restoring into the same database that is being read at the same time, that's not what I meant to suggest. I meant something more like `BEGIN; for every table loop DELETE FROM table; INSERT INTO table SELECT* FROM new_schema.table; end loop; COMMIT;`.

Comment: @DanielVérité can't see how it's different from restoring database from an SQL dump in a single transaction, but I'll it.